# Is there a way to force stop a nifi processor at the server level?

Tags: multithreading, apache-nifi, kill-process

I see this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NIFI-78 on jira but it's referencing java. Is there a way to map the nifi process with a thread on the server so I can manually kill it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There short answer is... no there is not a way to force kill a stuck processor, you would have to restart the NiFi server.

Longer explanation...

The NiFi application is a single Java process and this process then uses Java threads to concurrently execute the processors.

If the code in a processor gets stuck doing something, then the thread that was executing the processor is stuck, which is usually when you see a persistent number in the top-right corner of a processor.

The most common case of a processor getting stuck is when it uses a client library to make a connection to an external system, and the system is not responding and the client library does not provider good configurable timeout properties, or it does but the processor did not set them.

If this is a processor provided by Apache NiFi then we can file a bug and try to improve the processor to avoid these situations.

If it is a custom processor then it is up to the developer to follow best practices to avoid these conditions.

Comment: So, just so I understand, when the UI says a processor is stopped but some thread is still running, the only option I have is to restart the nifi server?

Comment: Unfortunately yes, sometimes it may just take a while to finish what it was doing, but if the number in the top-right corner is never going away then a restart will be needed.

Comment: Is this happening with a specific processor provided by Apache NiFi? Just asking to see if there is something we can address to make it better.

Comment: In our case Bryan SelectHiveQL processor is stuck and unable to stop/start again.

Comment: This answer is a bit old now and in the latest versions of NiFi there is a new feature to terminate stuck threads, it was introduced in 1.6.0 or maybe 1.7.0

Comment: @BryanBende when i restart nifi,all processor still show run,why?i can do anything cauze the UI is stuck.can u give me some suggestion?thanks in advance